# How to get Linux drivers for my (unsupported) hardware?

Tags: drivers, windows, keyboard

I recently bought a new keyboard with several special functions. These include key lights, macro keys, profiles, and some multimedia keys. However, the driver for the keyboard is only for windows, and it's on a CD (I found drivers on the internet, but they're the same and also for Windows). I tried installing the configuration tool with WINE but using it doesn't seem to affect any of the settings for my keyboard.

So the biggest problem is that changing any settings on the configuration tool and then saving doesn't seem to do anything. Another annoying problem is that pressing any lock key doesn't affect the LED, but does affect the lock on the system. (So pressing CAPS lock makes everything caps like normal, but the LED for <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> doesn't change. Same for <kbd>NumLock</kbd>, and <kbd>ScrollLock</kbd>. The <kbd>NumLock</kbd> LED gets turned on on startup but won't change after.) However, the normal keys that are on any keyboard such as letters, numbers and symbols work fine.

I have tried using the additional software tool but even with the CD inserted the driver won't show up. I can view the CD and open the manual, and install the driver with WINE. But installing it with WINE only installs the config tool which doesn't even work. I have also seen many questions for installing windows drivers but none of them seemed to apply to my case, as they either were fixed using additional software tool or ndiswrapper, which is apparently only for wireless card drivers.

How do I install the config tool(and the driver, if necessary) in a way that it actually changes the settings on the keyboard? It doesn't really have to be done with WINE but I'd rather use the most hassle-free way.

If it makes a difference, I am using Zorin, and the keyboard in question is the Sharkoon Skiller Pro.

Comment: I don't think you can install Windows drivers for use on a Linux OS (using wine or anything else).

Comment: Zorin is off topic on askUbuntu (refer to http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic please). I would follow #2 from the list from Fabby.

Comment: @Rinzwind I'm pretty sure Zorin is hugely based on Ubuntu and designed to be the same on system level, just redesigned to be more like Windows on user level.

Comment: @latias1290 that is not the point. it is NOT an -official- release and we are an -official- support platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [cannot install Windows drivers using Wine](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-8021e00ae87d4fbfb607739). You basically have 3 options:

1. Call the manufacturer of your keyboard and ask then for a Linux module. They will say they don't support it.
   Tell them you're willing to help them install a Linux system and that *every single Linux system* comes with full development tools like a compiler, a DDK, and that it will cost them only *an old PC lying in the basement* and some time.
   Point out to them that there are people like you who do buy brand new hardware and do gaming and other advanced stuff.
   Point out that if they have Linux drivers, they will sell more hardware as Linux customers are *loyal* to their manufacturers.
   That they do not have to pay anyone to use the [image: Linux compatible logo] Linux compatible logo!
2. Ask for your money back.
3. Get involved yourself: You have the hardware!  Start developing...  Help the community.  Maybe someone already is doing this and you can help them and the rest of the world!

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, therefore "accepting" the answer, which is better then saying "thank you" as both of our reputations will go up!  ;-)